# Magento 2.2.4 Admin issue on PHP 7.1

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, php-7, http-error-500, magento2.2.4

magento 2.2.4 was working absolutely fine with PHP 7.0 and when i upgrade PHP to 7.1 than the frontend is working fine but the backend is giving me below error.

Can anyone please guide me if PHP 7.1 is compatible with magento 2.2.4? and if its compatible than how i can resolve below issue?

[image: magento 2.2.4 backend issue with php 7.1]

thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at [php support](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/prereq/php-ubuntu.html) you will see it is supported. My advice would be to look at your web server logs and check the magento logs to see exactly what's causing the 500 error

Comment: I did the same but webserver logs saying simply http 500 error and magento logs saying nothing at all

Comment: Do you have mod_version enabled in apache?

Comment: Yes. It is enabled since i am using php 7.0

Comment: The weird thing is. Its only giving error when i am try to access backend admin. But frontend is working absolutely fine....

Comment: I presume this is not production so https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34629697/how-to-turn-on-error-messages-in-magento-2 may help

Comment: thanks but i tried this already and still its giving same issue

Answer (score 0):

i found the issue under pub/error_log file and it was below

**[19-May-2018 12:10:43 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  The file public_html/app/code/xyzmodule/Core/Model/Action.php was encoded by the ionCube Encoder for PHP 5.6 and cannot run under PHP 7.1 or later.
 Please ask the provider of the script to provide a version encoded with the ionCube Encoder for PHP 7.1. in Unknown on line 0**

this issue is with third party module provider and we ask them for the fixed Action.php file which should be compatible with PHP 7.1

apologies for the trouble. This question should be close now.

thank you

Comment: Ahaa ionCube Encoder  - i faced that issue too :) for PHP 5.4 and 5.6.

Comment: yes. it took my whole day to find that out :(